# How do I scale EC2 and push out code / data to my instances?

Tags: windows, iis, amazon-ec2, rds

I currently have a T1.micro for development running Windows with SQL server 2008.

The system allows students to come to our site to search for a mentor, update their profile with pictures and employment history etc. Roughly the same sort of work as a LinkedIn profile.

I need this to be able to scale very quickly without wasted resources.

I understand the following is important.

Separation of data, application etc. I will achieve this I think by hosting images using S3, Database instance via RDS and upgrade the EC2 instance.

**My Question**

How do I push data / code out to multiple ec2 / RDS instances seamlessly?

Answer (score 1):

For database you can easily use RDS, as its a shared DB resource.

but for code you can use any Remote filesystem, like NFS or GlusterFS. But i would recommend GlusterFS more, due to its feature set and abilities, which are not present in NFS.

You can create a single server, to become the GlusterFS server, which will host all the data and share it among any number of servers.

Also, this may be helpful:

[Need a recommendation for shared storage on auto-scaling ec2 w/ scalr](https://serverfault.com/questions/440682/need-a-recommendation-for-shared-storage-on-auto-scaling-ec2-w-scalr)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329980/sharing-storage-between-instances

Comment: GlusterFS doesn't run on windows though does it?

Comment: The Root node or Data server must be installed on Linux instance, clients can be linux or windows. Here is solution: http://gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/Gluster_3.2:_Accessing_Data_-_Setting_Up_GlusterFS_Client

Comment: updated the answer as well